# Can app engin handle https on the back end? If so, how to configure?

Tags: go, google-app-engine

we have a server which is being proxied by nginx in gae flex.  The configuration works fine so long as we are speaking http to the proxy.  FWIW, outside app engine the server works fine.

When we switch to https, we are getting error 400. The logs refer to unrecognised protocol.
There is very little information coming through.

The app itself is a golang http/https server.   In the docker registry nginx proxy container there is a requirement to alert the proxy using an environment variable. Naturally the GAE proxy can't be configured that way that I can discern.  But there must be something I need to set up in app.yaml or associated files?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine is behind the Google Front-End (GFE) where it has the default app engine load balancer. From what I can recall, that load balancer is where the https is terminated and your app engine instance ultimately receives the traffic as http.

1. Why do you need to use GAE flex as a proxy? What kind of service is it a proxy for (is it a proxy for another service in App Engine)?
2. Would you be able to share what you're seeing in your logs?
3. Would you be able to share your app.yaml?
4. Did you configure the GAE firewall at all?
5. When hitting your proxy, are you using the `<project-id>.appspot.com` url? If using a custom domain, did you setup a https cert?